# My question was marked as possible duplicate even though I had already addressed the specific other question

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

In this question [Docker not running on OS/X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37778439/4284627)

I had already explicitly called out the difference with an earlier question:

[Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos)

But now someone has marked it as a duplicate *of that same earlier question* without justification. This seems like they did not actually read my entire question.

It makes no sense to follow the standard directions of "edit the question to make the differences clear" - since that was already done.

So what should be done here?

Comment: it's a *possible* duplicate so maybe this person didn't read well the question. But you don't have to worry since it's not closed. You can also add comment to tell this person about your opinion, he may retract his flag

Comment: Ah, my *favorite* (not really) kind of duplicate vote. The kind that makes following standard procedure seem like a complete and utter waste of your time.

Comment: There is no point in getting upset about a single vote on a 2 year old question.  It is okay for an SO user to get it wrong sometimes, it takes 5 to do any real damage.  Easy to get rid of the comment, simply flag it as "no longer needed".

Comment: You can also ping the specific user who flagged your question to let them know; this lets them be able to retract their flag if they care to do so (which they probably will when they realize the flag will get declined because it's not the correct duplicate)

Comment: I've retracted vote as I potentially misread the question about the main cause, furthermore I've edited the post for further clarification.